# find Prestashop shop available languages within a module

Tags: php, module, prestashop

Good day all.
I'm doing a Prestashop module, and actually I'm using this logic in the .tpl file:

```
{foreach $languages as $lang} 
...
{/foreach}
```

I'd like to move this kind of logic into the module PHP, and not into the .tpl file, because the logic is becoming a little complex and I don't like templates with logic in them.

The problem I have is that I can't find a way to get ALL the languages within a module (I'm not considering db queries at this stage, I'd switch to brutal fetch in case I didn't solve in a more smooth way).
actually, I can retrieve the actual language by using:

```
$this->context->language->id
```

it's cool but isn't enough, what I need is:

1. **all the current languages of this shop**
2. all the shops
3. all the languages of a gives shop

point 1 is the most important, but also point 2 and 3 are to be considered because I'd like to scale this solution also in multishop environments.

does anyone have a clue on whre I should start search?

does anyone can answer to point 1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily do it with `Language` class through static methods.

1. Languages of current shop: `Language::getLanguages(true, $this->context->shop->id);`
2. Languages of all shops `Language::getLanguages(true);`
3. Languages of given shop `Language::getLanguages(true, $whatever_shop_id);`

First parameter `true` is to get only active languages, set to `false` if you need all languages. You can also specify third parameter as `true` if you wish to retrieve only language IDs.